# Python Pdfminer Unicode text not extracting properly

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, pdfminer

i am trying to extract sinhala text from unicode encoded pdf file.
but the text is not extracting properly

the text in the PDF is:
කවුරුහරි ඔබෙන් ඇහුවොත්

the text extracted is:
කවුරුහරි ඔබෙන් ඇහුබ ොත්

a letter is replaced with another letter.
here is the code im using.

```
import io
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text

u = convert_pdf_to_txt('sinhala.pdf')
print(u)
```